# Internet router crashes when uploading large file on macbook "Uploading through Chrome/Google Drive/ Outlook"

Tags: file-upload

Internet works just fine, once I try to upload large files on google drive/chrome or even open outlook, the whole internet router reset. and internet connection dropped for all devices.

at the beginning i thought it is ISP issue, however limiting the bandwidth solved the problem. Google drive preference allows users to customise the bandwidth. Chrome, you can define a new limit from session setting, you can use this guideline
https://weaselzone.com/limit-upload-speed-in-google-chrome-for-individual-websites-without-plugins/

i couldnt solve the problem for outlook yet. if you have a solution let me know. thank you.